# Angular 5: load child component by parent id

Tags: angular-cli, angular-routing

I have this routing module

```
...
{
  path: ':product-name/details',
  component: DetailsComponent
},
...
```

But I need to load different child component based on the product-name

eg.
if product-name is banana load BananaComponent
if product-name is apple load AppleComponent
etc.

How can obtain it?

Comment: Do you want to create a specific component for each product or you want to create a component which can show data according to the product name?

Comment: I want to create a specific component for each product, but I must have a default component to load when there is a new product-name or a _standard_ product.
It's more similar to a switch: condition A load A, condition B load B, ... , default load Def